# Find all solutions to a complex equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to find all solutions to:
$$\cosh(z) = -1.$$
Taking $z=x+iy$, I have the following identities:
$$\cosh(z) = \cosh(x)\cos(y)+i\sinh(x)\sin(y),$$
and
$$\cosh(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^z+e^{-z}\right).$$

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second condition to reduce the problem down to

$$e^z+e^{-z}=-2$$

Add $2$ to both sides:

$$e^z+2+e^{-z}=0$$

Noticing that $e^z+2+e^{-z}=(e^{z/2}+e^{-z/2})^2$, this reduces to

$$e^{z/2}+e^{-z/2}=0$$

Or,

$$e^{z/2}=-e^{-z/2}=e^{\pi i-(z/2)}$$

Hence, we can equate the exponents after accounting for the period:

$$z/2=\pi i-(z/2)+2\pi in\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb Z$$

> $$z=(2n+1)\pi i\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: I think you mean $e^z+2+e^{-z}=(e^{z/2}+e^{-z/2})^2$

Comment: Could you please explain the third line more? About
$$e^z+2+e^{-z} = \left(e^z+e^{-z}\right)^2$$

Comment: Some inconsistency between your last two displayed formulas.

Comment: @Arthur I think I fixed it.

Comment: @M.Turner Notice that:$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$where in this case $a=e^{z/2}$ and $b=e^{-z/2}$.

Comment: @Lubin Perhaps that comment was late, but I do not think there are inconsistencies now.

Comment: @Simply I don't see how you got from the second to last line and the last line??

Comment: @M.Turner I added $z$ to both sides, then divided by three.

Comment: Well, $n=2$ in your final formula seems to give a putative solution of $\frac53\pi i$, which I don’t think is right. Indeed, I would have expected a “$+z$” as second term of your RHS in the next-last display.

Comment: @Simply Oh yes I see that now.

Comment: @Lubin Ah yes, I misplaced my $-1=e^{\pi i}$.

Comment: :-| Well, I fixed it up... finally.  XD I feel stupid sometimes...

Comment: @Simply you clearly know more than I :) so would this same approach be good for another problem like:
$$\tan(z) = i$$

Comment: @M.Turner No, that one is a tad uglier.  For that one, I recommend having $u=e^{zi},\frac1u=e^{-zi}$.  You'll then get an ugly quadratic that can be cleared with the quadratic formula.

Comment: @Simply what I've got so far is:
$$\frac{\sin z}{\cos z}=i\Rightarrow \frac{\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{iz}-e^{-iz}\right)}{\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\right)}=i\Rightarrow 2e^{iz}=0.\,\text{(after simplifying)}$$
So what would be next?

Comment: @M.Turner You must've done some simplifying wrong.  All the shown steps are right, and it leads to$$u-\frac1u=-\left(u+\frac1u\right)$$

Comment: @Simply yep, that's what I got. I've looked it up though and it says it goes to $e^{iz} = 0$ which has no solution. Apparently, it's known that $\tan z = i$ has no solution.

Comment: @M.Turner Ah, it appears that is right.  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan(i)

Answer (score 3):

$$\cosh(z) = \cosh(x)\cos(y)+i\sinh(x)\sin(y)=-1$$
then
$$\cosh(x)\cos(y)=-1~~~;~~~\sinh(x)\sin(y)=0$$
the second shows $y=k\pi$ or $x=0$. With  the first,

if $x=0$ then $\cosh x=1$ so $\cos y=-1$ shows $y=2k\pi+\pi$ that is $z=(2k\pi+\pi)i$.

if $y=k\pi$ then $\cos y=\pm1$ so $\cosh x=\pm1$ shows $x=0$ that is $z=(k\pi)i$.

so final answer is  $z=(2k\pi+\pi)i$.

Comment: Oh yes, very concise.

Comment: I've tried this approach with the problem $\cos^2(z) = 4$ and I've arrived at this:
$$\cos(z) = 2\Rightarrow \cos(x)\cosh(y) = 2,\,\sin(x)\sinh(y) = 0$$
Second shows $x=k\pi$ or $y=0$. With the first,
if $y=0$ then $\cosh(y) = 1$ so $\cos(x) = 2$ and this is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the same result as @SimplyBeautifulArt has is to notice that $\cosh(z)=\cos(iz)$, so you see that $iz=(2k+1)\pi$, thus $z=(2k+1)\pi i$, all $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: did you divide by $i$ to get $z$ on its own?